# Using windows authentication for database connection - Which user is used?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, iis-8

I have am ASP.NET Web API application that currently makes use of SQL Authentication when connecting to the database. I would like to change the connection to using Windows Authentication. In doing so, how do I specify the user that the web app, and therefore the database access, makes use of? I am using `IIS v8.5.9600.16384`

Answer (score 2):

I can't say I agree with using integrated for the applications DB access as it makes security a bit more challenging as well as the coding issues tied to always having to deal with the possibility of different priv's for each user but obviously I don't know all the requirements of your situation.

So to answer your question:

- If your connection string is set to `Intergated Security` the identity of the executing thread is used to provide the credentials.
- By default the identity of the ASP.NET Worker Process will be the network credentials tied to the identity.
- You can view the credentials like this:

  ```
  IPrincipal threadPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\nIsAuthenticated: {1}" +
      "\nAuthenticationType: {2}", 
      threadPrincipal.Identity.Name, 
      threadPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
      threadPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType);
  ```

You may set the identity via `impersonation` in the web.config or programatically.

Web.config:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```

Code: (using the creds of the HttpContext user) **this assumes that IIS is using integrated too**

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
impersonationContext = 
((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

//User is the HttpContext.User
//Insert your code that runs under the security context of the authenticating user here.

impersonationContext.Undo();
```

Comment: I tried making a method that would return the result from the Web API. The method returned `Name: "",IsAuthenticated:False,AuthenticationType: ""`. Basically the threadPrincipal.Identity.Name was empty as was the threadPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType

Answer (score 0):

You will have to turn off Anonymous Authentication and enable Windows Authentication via IIS Manager.

Comment: Why would that be? This is just a connection for the database not authentication for the web app itself.

Comment: Brainfart, I was thinking of pass thru and impersonation security. I have not tried this with WebAPI (nor IIS 8.5+) but if it's hosted in IIS the Thread pool identity for the site should be the be the current thread principal. Also note that there is a difference between Thread.CurrentPrincipal and HttpContext.Current.User.